# Active Directory user rights

Tags: active-directory, windows, access-control-list

I'm currently working on a ASP MVC Website solution that I retrieved from a predecessor, and I had to create an active directory machine to support the login implementation using it.

Upon a user's first login, we prompt him to set his password and we also update his description (which hold a generic account state used in a moniroting tool).

My problem is the following:

I can change the user's password using these lines of code (entry is the AD Entry of the user):

```
entry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldpassword, newPassword });
entry.CommitChanges();
```

But a few lines later, an update on its description fails:

```
entry.InvokeSet("description", new object[] { UserPasswordStatus.PasswordChanged.ToString() });
entry.CommitChanges();
```

Resulting in an "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: General access denied error".

When I go to the AD, and change the user's security to full control on himself (given on the "SELF" reference), these same lines go well.

My question here is: what do I precisely need to change to allow a user to change his description?
Obviously, I'd like it to be generic and applied by default on all my users.

As you might notice, I'm a developer and I'm not very used to the server administration itself, so please try to take it into account :)

Comment: This should either go on [SO] or [SF] – it's certainly not a good fit here (we're not dealing with professional server issues or development)

Comment: thought it was the correct place, since I think my issue is related to AD itself, not to code. Is this more likely a server fault related issue?

Comment: What you've done works - allowing the user rights to modify his AD user object will allow him to change his description... it will also let him change other attributes you might not want him to change, so you might want to remove that permission after first logon.  I'm not sure if there's a more granular option that will let a user change only his description attribute or not, but temporarily giving the user modify or full access rights over his AD user object isn't a bad approach either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely advise against giving an Active Directory user full control over his or her own account, even for a second. Even for a millisecond. One day, a security auditor will find out, and latch on to that fact and proceed to cloud your mind with fear and doubt and basically just make you hate life in general.

I don't even really like that idea of giving a user the ability to modify his or her own description, as a lot of administrators leverage that description field for their own purposes, and they don't want users mucking around with their own attributes and putting "witty" catch phrases in their descriptions and typical things like that, that users do.

But anyway, consider this...

The user accounts inherit inheritable permissions from the OU (Organization Unit) in which they reside. So, if all your application's users reside in a particular OU, then you can modify the ACL on that OU to include `SELF, Allow, Write Description` so that every user that gets created in that OU will inherit that same permission. This may actually show up as "Write general information," or "Write Public information" as the "description" attribute is actually a member of a [property set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755430(v=WS.10).aspx). The big upshot to this approach is that you only have to make the ACL modification once, instead of dynamically adjusting ACLs in your code every time a user logs into the web application.

Good luck, and watch out for [AdminSDHolder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

By default the SELF identity has write permission to several properties.  You could extend this by delegating write permission to the Description property at the domain level, but a better approach may be to execute the command in the context of a service account that has permission to modify the accounts, instead of impersonating the user.

[image]